# Kendo, Razor braces problems

Tags: razor, kendo-ui

I checked braces, brackets 100 times...I think they are correctly placed but I get

"Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @"

```
<script id="customercontactsTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
   @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
        .Name("TabStripCustomer")
        .SelectedIndex(0)
        .Items(items =>
        {
         items.Add().Text("Contacts").Content(obj => 

                 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelApp.Models.CustomerContacts>()
                    .Name("customercontacts")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                    columns.Bound(l => l.CustomerContactID);
                    columns.Bound(l => l.CustomerID);
                    columns.Bound(l => l.CustomerContactName);
                    columns.Bound(l => l.CustomerContactPhone);
                    columns.Bound(l => l.CustomerContactDuty);
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Model
                    (model=>{
                        model.Id(l => l.CustomerContactID);
                        model.Field(l=>l.CustomerContactID).Editable(false);
                        model.Field(l => l.CustomerID);
                        model.Field(l => l.CustomerContactName);
                        model.Field(l => l.CustomerContactPhone);
                        model.Field(l => l.CustomerContactDuty);
                             }
                     )
                    .Read(read => read.Action("CustomersContactsRead", "Customers", new { customerID = "#=CustomerID#" }))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("CustomersContactsEdit", "Customers"))
                    .Create(update => update.Action("CustomersContactsCreate", "Customers", new { customerID = "#=CustomerID#" }))
                    )
                    .Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit"))
                    .Pageable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .Editable(editing => editing.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                    {
                        toolbar.Create();
                        toolbar.Save();
                    })
                    .ToClientTemplate())



                                           );}))
```

Is there a braces code checker? Can you spot any error?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: This is a huge block of code. Generally, I use @(variable-to-display), and @{large code block to execute}

Comment: What View Engine do you use, Is it ASPX ?

Comment: .cshtml - VS2010, Entity Framework, C# with KendoUi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
Content(obj => @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelApp.Models.CustomerContacts>()
```

In razor you should use [template delegates](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx):

```
Content(@<text>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ModelApp.Models.CustomerContacts>()
```